# WPF Scale Transform and ScrollViewer - When Zoomed can't scroll beyond original size

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, zooming

I have a StackPanel inside of a ScrollViewer.

I have a slider that does a scale transform on the stackpanel to allow zoom-in and zoom-out functionality.  The problem is that when I zoom in, the scrollviewer doesn't treat the content as being 'bigger'.

So, if I scroll in a little and scroll as far right as I can go - it stops me before I get to the end of the content.  If I zoom back out to the untransformed level, I see that it's stopping exactly at that point.  If I zoom in a lot, I can only see a small fraction of my total content when I scroll all the way over.

I can change the TransformOrigin to control which side loses the most content; but I figure there should be some way for the scrollviewer (or another control?) to take care of it for me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you doing render transform, or layout transform? You should be doing the latter.